# How to delete all the odd ordinal items in a list?

Tags: python, list

I've searched on stackoverflow and saw some guy write this:

```
[item for item in yourlist if item % 2]
```

It didn't work for me.

My code is like this:

```
x = ['apple','fruit','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
for i in range(0,len(x),2):
    if i%2 !=0:
        x.pop(i)
print x
```

This can't work too. It says pop index out of range

How to do it?

Comment: You're mutating the `list` as you iterate over it.  Don't do that.

Comment: The indices of the items get changed while you are iterating over the list

Comment: @ I know each time I did the iteration, the ordinal number of each item except item0 has changed, but I can't figure out the other way at first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use slicing with a stride:

```
x = x[1::2]
```

or to select the odd items instead of the even ones:

```
x = x[::2]
```

The first takes every second element in the input list, starting from the second item. The other takes every second element from the list, starting at the first item.

Demo:

```
>>> x = ['apple', 'fruit', 'orange', 'fruit', 'lemon', 'fruit']
>>> x[1::2]
['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit']
>>> x[::2]
['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']
```

The original code only works if wanted to select just the even *values*, not for even indices. You can use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add indices to that loop:

```
>>> [f for i, f in enumerate(x) if i % 2]
['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit']
```

but slicing is way easier here.

Answer (score 3):

Your code fails, because you are trying to modifying the list which you are iterating, without considering the side effects.

```
x = ['apple','fruit','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
for i in range(0,len(x),2):
    if i%2 !=0:
        x.pop(i)
print x
```

**Note 1:** `range(0,len(x),2)` will produce `[0, 2, 4]` and none of which will succeed with the condition. So, I am going to assume that you meant `range(1,len(x),2)`

**Note 2:** Since you are iterating over `range(1,len(x),2)`, which is actually `[1, 3, 5]`, the `if` condition is obsolete.

When `i` is 1, we pop the element at 1. So what actually happens is

*Before popping element at 1*

```
x = ['apple','fruit','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
        0       1        2       3       4       5
```

*After popping element at 1*

```
x = ['apple','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
        0       1        2       3       4
```

The same way, when `i` becomes 3, we pop the element at 3

*Before popping element at 3*

```
x = ['apple','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
        0       1        2       3       4
```

*After popping element at 3*

```
x = ['apple','orange','fruit','fruit']
        0       1        2       3
```

Now, `i` becomes 5 and there is no element at location 5. That is why `x.pop(5)` raises

```
pop index out of range
```

error. You can confirm that with this program

```
x = ['apple','fruit','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
try:
    for i in range(1,len(x),2):
        if i%2 !=0:
            x.pop(i)
except IndexError, e:
    print e, x, i
```

The output would be like this

```
pop index out of range ['apple', 'orange', 'fruit', 'fruit'] 5
```

**Solution**

You can use slicing notation to get only the elements at even ordinal data like this

```
print x[::2]    # ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']
```

You can get the elements at odd ordinals like this

```
print x[1::2]   # ['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit']
```

Otherwise, you can use list comprehension to filter out the odd ordinal data, like this

```
x = ['apple','fruit','orange','fruit','lemon','fruit']
print [item for idx, item in enumerate(x) if idx % 2 == 0]
# ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']
print [item for idx, item in enumerate(x) if idx % 2 == 1]
# ['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit']
```